# How to filter List<CustomClass> based on several Checkboxes

Tags: c#, silverlight, class, filtering

I have an XML file converted to a List. A PaintClass has several parameters such as Color (red OR orange OR blue) or Texture (Smooth OR Glossy) etc..

Now I have a few Checkboxes so the user can determine what PaintClass he would like to see. For instance, he is able to select red AND orange AND blue at the same time, and then every PaintClass should show up. But when he selects the Smooth checkbox only the Red/Blue/Orange paint that has a Smooth texture should show up.

What is the best way to do this instead of a lot of If-statements?

Kind regards,
Niels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is:

```
List<Color> allowedColors = new List<Color>();
if (redCheckBox.IsChecked)
  allowedColors.Add(Color.Red);
.
.
.
List<Texture> allowedTextures = new List<Texture>();
if (smoothCheckBox.IsChecked)
  allowedTextures.Add(Texture.Smooth);
.
.
.

filtered = paintList.Where( p => allowedColors.Contains(p.Color) &&
                              allowedTextures.Contains(p.Texture));
```

Another way would be storing the color value inside the Tag property of the checkbox, and then iterating over the checkboxes:

```
redCheckBox.Tag = Color.Red;
blueCheckBox.Tag = Color.Blue;
// etc...

List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
foreach (Object control in checkboxContainer.Children)
{ 
  var c = (control as CheckBox);
  if ( null == c )
    continue;
  colors.Add(c.Tag as Color);
}
```

Comment: Nicely done, was about to suggest some linq magic, but you beat me to it :)

Comment: I also wanted LINQ, but I saw how it'll roll down into infinite conditions.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your checkbox handler:

```
List<Color> colorsToDisplay;

//add all colors that are checked to colorsToDisplay
//..

List<PaintClass> toDisplay =
    paintClassList.
    .Where(p => colorsToDisplay.Any(c => c == p.Color)
                && (smoothCheckbox.Checked ? p.IsSmooth : true ));
```